# java program crashes if I input alphabets at the output, please help to fix this

Tags: java

the below program should not crash if I enter alphabets (error pasted at the bottom); rather it should ask the user to enter a valid number.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final byte MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;
    final byte PERCENT = 100;
    int principal = 0;
    float monthlyInterest = 0;
    int numberOfPayments = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1,000 and 1,000,000.");

    while(true) {
        System.out.print("Principal: ");
         principal = scanner.nextInt();
        if (principal >= 1000 && principal <= 1000_000)
            break;
        System.out.println("Enter a valid input");
    }

    while(true) {
        System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate: ");
        float annualInterest = scanner.nextFloat();
        if (annualInterest > 0 && annualInterest <= 15) {
            monthlyInterest = annualInterest / PERCENT / MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter a value between 1 and 15");
    }

    while(true) {
        System.out.print("Period (Years): ");
        byte years = scanner.nextByte();
        if (years > 0 && years <= 30) {
            numberOfPayments = years * MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter a value between 1 and 30");
    }

    double mortgage = principal * (monthlyInterest * Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments))
            / (Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - 1);

    String mortgageFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mortgage);
    System.out.println("Mortgage: " + mortgageFormatted);



}
}
```

****Output #1** // when user input, Period as abc

```
Enter a number between 1,000 and 1,000,000.
Principal: 600
Enter a valid input
Principal: 2000
Annual Interest Rate: 0
Enter a value between 1 and 15
Annual Interest Rate: 3.5
Period (Years): abc
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:2002)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1956)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

****Output #2**** // When years data type is byte, but user input 300, instead of crashing, the
program should ask the user to enter a valid number

```
Enter a number between 1,000 and 1,000,000.
Principal: 1000000
Annual Interest Rate: 3.9
Period (Years): 300
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: Value out of range. Value:"300" 
Radix:10
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:2008)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1956)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: So, before using things like `.nextFloat` you can do a `.hasNextFloat` (or type equivalent) to check if the `Scanner` contains an expected value, otherwise you can go an whinge at the user till they do the right thing

Comment: Personally, I like to read the line and then do seperate parsing of it

Comment: Since you have already used nextInt() for "Principal", my question is: is there any reason you want to use nextByte() for "Period"? nextByte() will allow the scanner to accept alphanumeric values, when you are specifically interested in an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Try Catch, like this:

```
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Period (Years): ");
    try{
       byte years = scanner.nextByte();
       if (years > 0 && years <= 30) {
        numberOfPayments = years * MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
        break;
       }
       System.out.println("Enter a value between 1 and 30");
    catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Value must be numeric");
    }
}
```